# Change column view DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

The title may be a bit confusing, and I'll try my best in trying to explain my problem.

I have a horizontally scrollable `datagridview` and when I click a button on the menu bar, I want the `datagridview` to move the view to the specified column, while still having all columns still visible.

So For example I click on Fish, and then the `datagridview` should scroll/position itself to the first mention of Fish in the columns to show a section of the view all related to Fish, while still maintaining all other columns not related to Fish and viewable.

What I would like to know is, is the moving of the position of the view possible to do? I didn't know what to search up, and more or less the results of the search included re-ordering of the columns, which I do not want.

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve? You want to scroll to the column which contains Fish? Also, it depends upon whether the Fish is present in only column or multiple columns...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that it should scroll to the "Column Name" Fish. not a cell that contains the word Fish. The fish columns will be something like, `Fish Name`, `Fish Species`, `Fish Sex`, etc... So I want it to scroll to `Fish Name`.

Answer (score 0):

For a `DataGridView` with ***windows* *form*** --- give your `cell` to Particuler **Id**.
Like you want to assign a one `column` with `Fish` then

```
row.Cells["Name"].Value = Fish.Id;
```

and then on `click` `event` give `focus` to this **id**.

**Note:-** **for a better solution post your question with your `code`.**
**thanks**

Answer (score 0):

Replace `fish` to your search text and try it.

```
List<DataGridViewColumn> Cols = dataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>().Where(c => c.HeaderText.Contains("fish")).ToList();

            if (Cols.Count > 0)
            {
                dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex = Cols[0].Index;
            }
```

Above code will scroll down datagridview horizontally  to show searched text in column names.